# How to add multiple markers for single location on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps version 3 and would like to add two markers for a single location on the map.

One would be the default marker which appears with Google Maps, but second would show the name of the brand associated with that location.

My code is

```
    function initialize() {
            var filterLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.928184,72.832601);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: filterLatlng,
                zoom: 19,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: filterLatlng,
                title:"Filter Shop"
            });
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
```

Comment: And what is your question? Where is your attempt to add a second marker?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this library:
http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/maplabel/src/maplabel.js?r=303

It will allow you to add a label on the map.
That label will be attached to a hidden marker like you described.
The use is quite simple you should be able to figure it out quite easy.